# Getting ' ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency' while installing reactstrap

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, reactstrap

I'm getting the following error while installing RreactStrap in my project.

```
C:\Users\niles\user-management-beta> npm install --save reactstrap react react-dom

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.2
npm WARN   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm WARN     @testing-library/react@"^11.2.2" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (react-dom, the root project, reactstrap)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-popper@1.3.7
npm WARN node_modules/react-popper
npm WARN   react-popper@"^1.3.6" from reactstrap@8.8.0
npm WARN   node_modules/reactstrap
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^11.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!       @testing-library/react@"^11.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     react-dom@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (reactstrap)
npm ERR!   2 more (the root project, reactstrap)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from create-react-context@0.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-popper/node_modules/create-react-context
npm ERR!   create-react-context@"^0.3.0" from react-popper@1.3.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-popper
npm ERR!     react-popper@"^1.3.6" from reactstrap@8.8.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/reactstrap
npm ERR!       reactstrap@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\niles\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\niles\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-26T15_27_03_104Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\niles\user-management-beta>
```

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall NodeJS. Deleted and created a new project with the latest version. Tried all possible way. Could you please help me?

Comment: Certainly this is because of react-popper as it is not migrated to version v2.

Comment: I installed the react-popper, but still getting the same error. "react-popper": "^2.2.4",